# Screen share through finder - can't login to remote machine

Tags: finder, screen-sharing, remote-control

I want to display my iMac (13.3.1. Ventura) screen onto my Macbook Air (11.7.1 Big Sur).

I bring up a Finder window on the Macbook, and click "Go", "Network", and the finder window shows the iMac I'm trying to reach on the local wifi network.

I click on the iMac in the Finder window, and it shows a panel allowing me to choose between "Connect as" or "Share screen".
[image: panel showing 'connect as']

If I click on "Connect as", it brings up a panel inviting me to click "connect", then shows a panel allowing me to "connect as a registered user".   It also offers to connect using an Apple ID. (I'm not sure what my Apple ID is).

[image: login to remote screen panel]

I use user-id and passwd that I use to login on the iMac.
This panel takes a second, and then shakes itself - that's the wrong password or user id.
Except it is not.   Those are the exact credentials that I use when I login to the iMac, sitting in front of it.

If I choose "Share screen" instead, I get a slightly different panel, but I still cannot sign in remotely with the exact username and passwd that I login to the iMac with in person.

This used to work flawlessly.   What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do you have remote access right on the remote Mac?  Can other people remotely access the remote iMac?  Have you tried stopping remote access on the remote Mac and then re-enabling it?